# Procedure for Brachos Achronos

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating, meal-seudah

Let's say one says borei ha'adamah or ha'eitz and eats at least a kezayis of a fruit or vegetable, but is not yet full. Then, the person decides that he or she wants to eat bread. Is the proper procedure to say borei nefashos first, or to say hamotzi and then afterward say birkas hamazon and borei nefashos?

If the answer is that one should say the brachos achronos before hamotzi, what should one do if one forgets to do so before saying hamotzi? In such a situation, should one say it in the middle of the meal, or wait until after birkas hamazon?

Comment: Is he planning on eating any of the fruit/vegetable during the bread meal?

Comment: I don't know -- does the answer depend on that?

Answer (score 2):

[Mishnah Berura 176:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=141) -

If he is planning on eating more fruit during the meal, and had in mind to continue eating the fruit during the meal, then it is all considered part of the meal and he does not make a borei nefashos, not before hamotzi and not after, as it is covered by the birkas hamazon that he will say.

If he does not plan to continue eating more during the meal, then he needs to make a borei nefashos.  This borei nefashos should be made even during the meal.  The implication of the Mishnah Berura is that it doesn't matter at what point you make the borei nefashos, as the eating of the fruit had nothing to do with the meal, and it could even be after birkas hamazon.

If he ate a vegetable (or any food that does not need a beracha when eaten during the meal) then he makes a borei nefashos even if he eats more during the meal, as the original pre-meal eating was perforce not part of the meal.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused about your last sentence. Are you saying it's different between eating fruits and vegetables? Do you mean that he makes the borei nefashot before the meal in that case? Or is it just the same as the fruit example? (I guess the difference would be that one says ha-eitz even during a bread meal, if one already said borei nefashos?)

Comment: @Kordovero It is the same as fruit in the case that you do not plan to eat more during the meal.  In the case of a vegetable, it is automatically treated as if you do not plan to have more.